# List of large cities in Pakistan

Tags: bugs, curated-data, geography, geographics, entity

**Bug introduced in 12.2.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**

I am using v12.2.0-Win7-x64.

I have been experimenting with `Geo*` command syntaxes and came across something that is an obvious bug. I have left a `Tooltip` in the image below. The city of Amritsar is in India.

```
cities = TakeLargestBy[
  EntityValue[GeoEntities[Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], "City"], 
   "Population", "EntityAssociation"], Value @@@ # &, 20]
```

[image]

I would like to know if this is version dependent or if it can be replicated on other platforms/versions. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This bug is reproducible in 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: `TakeLargestBy[ EntityValue[GeoEntities[Entity["Country", "Russia"], "City"], 
  "Population", "EntityAssociation"], Value @@@ # &, 10]` performs an error "GeoEntities::timeout: A network operation for GeoEntities timed out. Please try again later." The same issue with "Ukraine".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice how the Amritsar region touches the border to Pakistan:

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Blue], 
 Polygon[Entity["City", {"Amritsar", "Punjab", "India"}]]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.25]
]
```

[image]

For this reason I think we need to use the option `"FullyContained" -> True` in `GeoEntities`.

```
TakeLargest[
  EntityValue[
    GeoEntities[Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], "City", "FullyContained" -> True], 
    "Population", "EntityAssociation"], 20]
```

[image]

---

Notice similar behavior in [`GeoWithinQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoWithinQ.html):

```
GeoWithinQ[
  Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], 
  Entity["City", {"Amritsar", "Punjab", "India"}]
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
GeoWithinQ[
  Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], 
  Entity["City", {"Amritsar", "Punjab", "India"}], 
  "FullyContained" -> True
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: Thanks @GregHurst. I learned something new. So it is not a bug? How do I know when to use this option?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or not... With the same logic since India touches Pakistan one might think it should be returned in this call, which it's not: `GeoEntities[Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], "Country"]`.

Comment: If I had to guess: this is probably a bug and the `"FullyContained"` option is mainly meant for features that can span multiple geographic regions, like lakes, rivers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with `GeoEntities`. `EntityClass` does not have this issue and can be used as a workaround.

```
EntityValue[
 EntityClass[
  "City", {EntityProperty["City", "Country"] -> Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], 
   EntityProperty["City", "Population"] -> TakeLargest[20]}],
 EntityProperty["City", "Population"], "EntityAssociation"]
```