# Most Populous Cities

Tags: entity

Consider the following code that generates an entity association for the top ten most populous cities in WV:

```
TakeLargest[EntityValue[GeoEntities[
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", "UnitedStates"}],"City"],
"Population", "EntityAssociation"], 10]
```

With output:

[image]

Cumberland is near the border of WV but is in Maryland. The question I have is how to manually get the correct results in spite of the apparent bug?

Comment: What is the question about Wolfram Language programming?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274789/list-of-large-cities-in-pakistan).

Comment: As shown in the link provided by @Syed, use the option `"FullyContained" -> True` in `GeoEntities`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

wva = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", "UnitedStates"}];

list1 = TakeLargest[
  EntityValue[GeoEntities[wva, "City"], "Population", "EntityAssociation"], 
  10]
```

[image]

Excluding border cities that "spill into" WVA

```
list2 = Pick[
  list1, #[[1]]["AdministrativeDivision"] === wva & /@ (list1 // Normal)]
```

[image]

Using the option `"FullyContained"->True` excludes border cities that "spill into" WVA; however, it also excludes border cities that "spill out" of WVA

```
list3 = TakeLargest[
  EntityValue[GeoEntities[wva, "City", "FullyContained" -> True], 
   "Population", "EntityAssociation"], 10]
```

[image]

Items from `list2` that are excluded from `list3`, i.e., "spilled out"

```
Complement[list2, list3]
```

[image]

Taking top ten from combined `list2` and `list3`

```
list4 = Join[list2, list3][[;; 10]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon I tried "FullyContained"-> True and lost Wheeling, Huntington, and Weirton as you did. Your explanation of spilling into and out of WV was great.